# React-Redux why isn't my code removing items from the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've been working on a shopping cart where once I click on a product it shall remove it but it doesn't. I've used UUID to assign to the products that I am adding and then i pass it to the reducer and after that I save it into the state as id then on the removeProduct case I am filtering the state to remove that exact product with that exact ID but it doesn't remove it. It just stays like that. How can I fix that?

Here are the files related to this problem:
index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {store} from './store'
import {Button, Nav, Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavItem, NavLink} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {LinkContainer} from 'react-router-bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import {MdShoppingBasket, MdAddShoppingCart} from 'react-icons/md'
import './index.css'
import uuid from 'uuid/v4'
class index extends Component {
    render() {        
        const {productsInCart} = this.props;
        const productsList = [
            {
                name: 'Cool Hat',
                price: 50, 
                image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/4429555/pexels-photo-4429555.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260'
            },
            {
                name: 'Dull Hat',
                price: 5, 
                image: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/4429555/pexels-photo-4429555.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=750&w=1260'
            },]
        const addProduct=(product)=>
        {
            store.dispatch({type: 'addToCart', name: product.name, price: product.price, image: product.image, id: uuid()})
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar className ='navbar' variant='light'>
                    <NavbarBrand>Home</NavbarBrand>
                    <Nav className='ml-auto'>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink href='/cart'>
                                <span className='cartIndicator'><MdShoppingBasket size={25}></MdShoppingBasket>
                                <span>{productsInCart.length}</span></span>
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar>
                {productsList.map((product, id)=>
                <div className='productsList' key={id}>
                    <div className='productShow'>
                    <h3 className='productName'>{product.name}</h3>
                    <img className='productImage'src={product.image}></img>
                    <p className='productPrice'><strong>$ {product.price}.00</strong></p>
                    <Button className='addProductButton' variant='success' onClick={()=>addProduct(product, id)}> <MdAddShoppingCart size={20}></MdAddShoppingCart> <strong>Add to cart </strong> </Button>

                    </div>
                </div>)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps=(state={productsInCart: [{}]})=>
{
    return{
        productsInCart: state.productsInCart
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(index);
```

reducers.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery'
import uuid from 'uuid/v4'
const reducer = (state={productsInCart:[{}]}, action)=>
{
    let nextId = 0;
    switch(action.type)
    {
        case 'addToCart':
            return{
                
                ...state,
                productsInCart: [...state.productsInCart, {name: action.name, price: action.price, image: action.image, id: action.id }]            
            }
            
        case 'clearCart':
            return{
                ...state,
                productsInCart: []   
            }
        case 'removeProduct':
            return{
                ...state, 
                productsInCart:[...state.productsInCart.filter(product=>product!==action.id)]}
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export default reducer;
```

cart.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button, Nav, Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavItem, NavLink} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {MdHome} from 'react-icons/md'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {store} from './store'
class cart extends Component {
    render() {
        const {productsInCart} = this.props;
        const clearCart=()=>
        {
            store.dispatch({type: 'clearCart'})
        }
        const removeProduct=(id)=>
        {
            store.dispatch({type:'removeProduct'})
           

        }
        
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar variant='dark' bg='success'>
                    <NavbarBrand>Your cart</NavbarBrand>
                    <Nav className='ml-auto'>
                        <NavItem>
                            <NavLink href='/home'>
                                <MdHome size={25}></MdHome>
                            </NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar>
                {productsInCart.map((product, index)=>
                <div className='productsList'>
                    <div className='productShow'>
                    <h3 className='productName'>{product.name}</h3>
                    <img className='productImage'src={product.image}></img>
                    <p className='productPrice'><strong>$ {product.price}.00</strong></p>
                    <Button variant='danger'><strong onClick={()=>removeProduct(index)}>Remove product</strong></Button>
                    </div>

                </div>)}
                <Button onClick={()=>clearCart()}>Clear Cart</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
    
}
const mapStateToProps=(state={productsInCart: [{}]})=>
{
    return{
        productsInCart: state.productsInCart
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(cart);
```

Comment: You've written `state.productsInCart.filter(product=>product!==action.id)`. This is comparing products against the action ID, and I don't imagine a product will ever equal an action ID. Did you perhaps want to compare product IDs against  the action ID?  If so, try `state.productsInCart.filter(product=>product.id!==action.id)` instead.

Comment: I've actually found the solution a couple of seconds ago, I will post it in detail in a while, but I appreciate that you took your time to respond to my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found the solution and basically I had to change the ID's a bit. I've manually added an ID to my products in index.js and then whenever I press the add to cart button I assign this ID to the products, like so:
`const addProduct=(product)=>{store.dispatch({type: 'addToCart', name: product.name, price: product.price, image: product.image, id: product.id})}`
Then I've changed my reducer a bit. That is how my removeProduct case looks like:
`case 'removeProduct': let updatedCart = [...state.productsInCart] const index = state.productsInCart.findIndex(product=>product.id===action.id) console.log(index) if(index>=0 || index>=-1) { updatedCart.splice(index,1) } return{ ...state, productsInCart: updatedCart }`
Basically what is going on here is I first initialized a new instance of my Cart, that is a total copy of the current cart, that would hold the values of the new one after removing the selected element, then I created a variable that would have to find the index in the state of the item that I want to be removed and once that is found I make sure that I found it by using that if statement above, once it returns true(meaning the element has been found and ready to be removed) I call the splice function of the updatedCart holder and I tell it to remove the element, then after the element is removed I simply add the updatedCart to the state and it is shown to the user.